# Trouble installing Yeoman; "archive/0.9.5.tar.gz" not found

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to install yeoman but it seems that the following url no longer works/may have been removed from github:

I'm running:
`npm install -g yeoman`

->
`npm ERR! fetch failed` `http://github.com/yeoman/generators/archive/0.9.5.tar.gz`

The github repository no longer seems to exist. What should I do? Thank you!

The link is [here](http://github.com/yeoman/generators/archive/0.9.5.tar.gz) to make it easy for others to go there.

Thank you for your time and patience reading this; I just started trying to use NodeJS so I am sure the fault is on my end somehow.

Answer (score 1):

`npm install -g yo`

Please refer to our official documentation on our website: http://yeoman.io/

The `yeoman` binary has not updated/used in > 4 years.